# Binary Search Tree deletion function in C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I'm implementing a binary search tree, but my node deletion function does not work properly:

```
void remove_node(treePointer *root, element data)
{
    treePointer next, temp;
    treePointer *left;
    treePointer *p = root;
    treePointer removed;
//    while(1)
//    {
//        if(*p == NULL)
//        {
//            printf("error\n");
//            return;
//        }
//        else if((*p)->data == data)
//            break;
//        else if((*p)->data > data)
//            p = &((*p)->left_child);
//        else
//            p = &((*p)->right_child);
//    }
    removed = search(*root, data);
    p = &removed;
    if((*p)->left_child == NULL)
        next = (*p)->right_child;
    temp = *p;
    *p = next;
    free(temp);

}
```

Using the commented code performs the deletion correctly, but instead using the `search()` function (below) does not.

```
treePointer search(treePointer root, element data)
{
    if(!root) return NULL;
    if(data == root->data) return root;
    if(data < root->data)
        return search(root->left_child, data);
    return search(root->right_child, data);
}
```

Here is the struct definition:

```
typedef int element;
typedef struct tree *treePointer;
typedef struct tree
{
    element data;
    treePointer left_child;
    treePointer right_child;
} tree;
```

What's wrong?

Comment: your search function is returning the node to remove, but you want a reference to its parent so you can change its parent's child pointer. typedef'ing a struct pointer obfuscates the code IMO. You are missing a check that `search` didn't return NULL.

Comment: is this the final version remove_node function? I am asking this because you have not handled the case where `(*p)->left_child` is NOT Null.